# how to override execution of default Insert query while using @SQLInsert annotation in grails/gorm

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I want to insert/update/delete records in DB using function/procedure. How can i do this in GORM using @SQLInsert annotation. when i save the object i want the function in @sqlInsert to be executed and not the regular insert. Can anyone help?

```
below is the entity class:

@SQLInsert(callable = true,  sql = "{? = call db1.user_api.ins(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }")
class user{

    BigDecimal userid
    String createBy
    String updateBy
    Calendar updateDts
    Calendar createDts
    String createPgm
    String updatePgm
    String userName

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'abc'
        id name: "userid"
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'user_seq']
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        createPgm maxSize: 900
        updatePgm maxSize: 900
    }

}


below is how i am calling it:
            user pf = new user();
            pf.setCreateBy("abc")
            pf.setCreateDts(calendar);
            pf.setUpdateBy("abc");
            pf.setUpdateDts(calendar);
            pf.setCreatePgm(updatePgm);
            pf.setUpdatePgm(updatePgm);
            pf.setUserName(username);
            pf.save()
```

currently when i call save on pf , insert statement gets executed instead of function.

Comment: Why do you want to use @SQLInsert?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Why do you need to modify the Hibernate INSERT query?

Comment: In our project we follow a process where we do all in inserts/delete/updates through functions .Its a requirement i would say.

Comment: Well technically, they *are* being done through functions. It's part of the magic that Hibernate does. :) Why is rolling your own SQL a project requirement? To me, that's like buying a car and then cutting out the floor boards in order to push it along like the Flintstones.